# NFA to DFA: Removing unnecessary states - What is NEW start state?

Tags: logic, finite-automata

I'm trying to understand the transformation scheme from NFA to DFA, and think I have grasped most of it (in terms of method).

The original NFA is the following:

[image]

And the DFA was constructed by:

[image]

However, the above example shows an NFA before unnecessary states have been removed, as well as after removal. Unnecessary referring to states with no incoming arrows.

**QUESTION**

How do you determine what the **NEW** initial state will be? I see that it is set to be {1,3}, but why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you give the original NFA?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Updated in question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The starting state of the DFA is the set of all states of the original NFA that can be reached from the starting state of the original NFA using only $\epsilon$-transitions. I.e., it is the set of all states that you could be in in the original NFA after reading the word $\epsilon$. Note that in general, the state of the DFA that you are in after reading the word $w$, is the set of states that you could be in in the original NFA after reading the word $w$.

For this particular case, that amounts to $\{1,3\}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped me a bunch.