# NFA to DFA: new initial state

Tags: automata

Question 4 asks to convert this NFA to a DFA:

[image: Q4 asks to convert this NFA to a DFA]

The solution is as follows:

[image: Solutions' DFA]

Whereas I found this as a solution (excuse the messy layout):

[image: My DFA (excuse the messy layout)]

My DFA is identical to the solutions' except the initial state (underlined).

The solutions omitted the **0** state (NFA initial state) and made **1,3** the DFA initial state (mine stays **0**).

Can anybody please explain why they removed the **0** state and made **1,3** initial instead?

***Edit**: the original Q has been answered, but the following NFA to DFA    doesn't seem to follow:*

[image]

The DFA -

I've changed the labels for comprehension:
[image]

But shouldn't the new initial state be **1,4** (not in DFA)?

Answer (score 3):

Okay I stumbled on another thread that explains it well:
[https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1809453/nfa-to-dfa-removing-unnecessary-states-what-is-new-start-state#:~:text=1%20Answer&text=The%20starting%20state%20of%20the,after%20reading%20the%20word%20%CF%B5](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1809453/nfa-to-dfa-removing-unnecessary-states-what-is-new-start-state#:%7E:text=1%20Answer&text=The%20starting%20state%20of%20the,after%20reading%20the%20word%20%CF%B5).

Basically, the new DFA's initial state is the set of all states the NFA's initial state reached using only epsilon transitions.

Comment: Exactly: for all practical purposes the NFA has two initial states.

Comment: This Q removes the original initial state, but a Q in this same tut kept the original initial state and didn't include the new initial state (this new state wasn't in the DFA at all).  So which do you choose when drawing the DFA? @Brian M. Scott

Comment: I’d have to see the other example.

Comment: I edited in the other example @Brian M. Scott

Comment: It doesn’t really matter whether you label it $0$ or $1,4$: it’s the transitions that are important. Labelling it $1,4$ is thinking of the NFA as having two initial states and ignoring its state $0$; labelling it $0$ is treating it the same way but giving it the label of the original initial state. I prefer the $1,4$ label, but that’s mostly a matter of taste.

Comment: Thanks for the input Brian

Comment: My pleasure. $ $